# Android spinner item cannot be selected when not creating from resource

Tags: android, kotlin, spinner

I am using kotlin and android 8.0, I have 2 spinners in my code, 1 of them was created using a string array from resource and another was created with an ArrayList. For the spinner that was created with an ArrayList, when clicking on the item, it does not run the OnItemSelected function and does not update the spinner.

Here is my kotlin code for the spinner

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val modules = ArrayList<Module>()
        val bufferedReader = BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(resources.openRawResource(R.raw.mod_code)))
        var line = bufferedReader.readLine()
        while(line != null) {
            val values = line.split(",")
            modules.add(Module(values[0].replace("\uFEFF", "").toInt(), values[1], values[2].replace("\uFEFF", "").toDouble()))
            line = bufferedReader.readLine()
        }

        val moduleCodeArray = ArrayList<String>()
        val yearSpinner: Spinner = findViewById(R.id.year)
        yearSpinner.onItemSelectedListener = object : AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener{
            override fun onItemSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?, view: View?, position: Int, id: Long) {
                val item = parent?.getItemAtPosition(position).toString()
                Toast.makeText(parent?.context, "Selected: $item", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

                moduleCodeArray.clear()
                for(module in modules) {
                    if(module.year == position + 1) {
                        moduleCodeArray.add(module.moduleCode)
                    }
                }
            }
            override fun onNothingSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?) {
            }
        }
        ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
                this,
                R.array.years,
                R.layout.custom_spinner
        ).also { adapter ->
            adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.custom_spinner_dropdown)
            yearSpinner.adapter = adapter
        }


        println(moduleCodeArray)
        val moduleCodeSpinner = findViewById<Spinner>(R.id.module_code)
        moduleCodeSpinner.onItemSelectedListener = object : AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
            override fun onItemSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?, view: View?, position: Int, id: Long) {
                val item = parent?.getItemAtPosition(position).toString()
                Toast.makeText(parent?.context, "Selected: $item", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }

            override fun onNothingSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?) {}
        }

        ArrayAdapter(
            this,
            R.layout.custom_spinner,
            moduleCodeArray
        ).also { adapter ->
            adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.custom_spinner_dropdown)
            moduleCodeSpinner.adapter = adapter
        }

    }
}
```

EDIT: I have fixed the problem! In the code I provided, you can see my ArrayList being filled in an onItemSelected function, for some reason, the ArrayAdapter has to be in that function as well, so the correct code should look something like this.

```
val modules = ArrayList<Module>()
        val bufferedReader = BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(resources.openRawResource(R.raw.mod_code)))
        var line = bufferedReader.readLine()
        while(line != null) {
            val values = line.split(",")
            modules.add(Module(values[0].replace("\uFEFF", "").toInt(), values[1], values[2].replace("\uFEFF", "").toDouble()))
            line = bufferedReader.readLine()
        }

        val moduleCodeArray = ArrayList<String>()
        val moduleCodeSpinner = findViewById<Spinner>(R.id.module_code)
        val yearSpinner: Spinner = findViewById(R.id.year)
        yearSpinner.onItemSelectedListener = object : AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener{
            override fun onItemSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?, view: View?, position: Int, id: Long) {
                val item = parent?.getItemAtPosition(position).toString()
                Toast.makeText(parent?.context, "Selected: $item", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

                moduleCodeArray.clear()
                for(module in modules) {
                    if(module.year == position + 1) {
                        moduleCodeArray.add(module.moduleCode)
                    }
                }

                ArrayAdapter(
                    applicationContext,
                    R.layout.custom_spinner,
                    moduleCodeArray
                ).also { adapter ->
                    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.custom_spinner_dropdown)
                    moduleCodeSpinner.adapter = adapter
                }
            }
            override fun onNothingSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?) {
            }
        }
        ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
                this,
                R.array.years,
                R.layout.custom_spinner
        ).also { adapter ->
            adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.custom_spinner_dropdown)
            yearSpinner.adapter = adapter
        }

        moduleCodeSpinner.onItemSelectedListener = object : AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
            override fun onItemSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?, view: View?, position: Int, id: Long) {
                val item = parent?.getItemAtPosition(position).toString()
                Toast.makeText(parent?.context, "Selected: $item", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }

            override fun onNothingSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?) {}
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Code Seems correct , I have used the same code provided by you and it worked correctly.

May you have error in custom_spinner or custom_spinner_dropdown !![You can share these layouts ]

This is what I have done:
[spinner example](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1FyeHvirVIkZSaZKbtZ35GubDwlLS8xRt/view?usp=drivesdk)

Comment: Thanks for providing your app, I've copied your xml files for the spinners but unfortunately it still does not work.

Comment: I've edited my question to include the full code